# SWI Prolog documentation generator tags environment: tag not allowed

Tags: errors, amsmath

I'm trying to generate documentation using SWI Prolog PlDoc package, but I'm running into a problem with the environment defined in `pldoc.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\tag}[1]{%
    \item[#1]}
...
%   \begin{tags} ... \end{tags}

\newenvironment{tags}%
    {\begin{quote}\begin{description}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
        \footnotesize}%
    {\end{description}\end{quote}}
```

This is used in the generated TeX file as follows:

```
\subsection{automata.pl: High-level predicates for dealing with regular expressions}

\label{sec:automata}

\begin{tags}
    \tag{See also}
\url{https://github.com/wvxvw/intro-to-automata-theory}
    \tag{To be done}
Add \predref{match_suffix_regex}{3}, \predref{match_all_regex}{3}, \predref{find_regex}{3}
\end{tags}
```

Which I insert into a larger document as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
...
\usepackage{amsmath}
...
\usepackage{pldoc}
...
\begin{document}
...
\section{Appendix A}
\label{sec:orgheadline18}
\input{automata-doc}
\end{document}
```

When I try to generate PDF using `latexmk` with `pdflatex` I receive the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.253     \tag
              {See also}
```

However, when I generate standalone documentation (which does not use `amsmath` package), this error doesn't happen.  My guess is that `amsmath` is messing things up, but I don't know how to prevent it from interfering.

Comment: `\tag` is an important command in `amsmath` -- the definition in your `.sty` file clashes here. Since I've no access to `pldoc.sty` I can't test, but I suggest to copy the `\tag` definition from `pldoc.sty` and rename it `\pltag`, as well replacing any `\tag{...}` in your real document with `\pltag{...}` accordingly.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer technically, the `.sty` isn't my. Should I write to the maintainer to alert them to the problem, or is this something that I can remedy locally (without having to modify the said `.sty`)?

Comment: You should not modify the `.sty` at all. Writing to the maintainer is certainly a good idea

Comment: Note that LaTeX must have given earlier errors. It will have told you that `\tag` was not available to be created as a new command, for example. You ignore such errors at your peril!

Comment: @cfr ouch, I had to scroll the log upwards more... For some reason this particular `.sty` defines a whole bunch of commands defined elsewhere... for instance `\secref`, `\appref`, `\figref`, `\mod`... Is there any reason someone would want to re-define commands like this? It's hard to believe this is a coincidence.

Comment: Well, a publisher might if they don't want you using those package anyway. That way, you don't have to change the source much in order to produce the output they want. Same way different classes all define `\section{}`. That's not coincidence either! But since this package isn't part of TeX Live and I have no idea what it is for or where to find it, I can't say whether this has any relevance or not ;).

Comment: @cfr in case you wanted to: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-pldoc/blob/master/pldoc.sty here's the `.sty`. Its purpose is to support the code generated by Prolog (programming language) documentation generator. One way of using the generator is to produce TeX suitable for `\input`, so that's unlikely that they don't want me to use other packages.

Comment: is there any news here?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, I didn't update the question with the info: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-pldoc/issues/11 I wrote to the maintainers, and this was their response. The way I "managed" to work around was by compiling a separate PS pages for the Prolog documentation and then including them in the final PDF as images / adding them as pages to the already existing PDF.

Comment: @wvxvw -- thanks for reporting back.  it would be nice to take this question off the unanswered list.  there are a couple of ways to do that -- close it (as unlikely to help someone else, although that's not an "authorized" reason any more), or post an answer, which can be a self-answer.  i think the latter would be reasonable here, so please do.  after a required delay (i think it's a couple of days) you can accept it.  (thanks for reporting back.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the maintainer isn't willing to change the STY provided with the documentation generator: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-pldoc/issues/11

I lack the knowledge to try to patch this myself, so, the only way I found around the problem was to generate the code documentation and the rest of the article separately and then join the two resulting PDFs following these (or similar) instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/18691/638782

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I modified the Prolog and LaTeX code to
get things right. You can find the modified files and some instructions on GitHub in the repository AltPldoc.
https://github.com/francomorando/AltPldoc